# How can I loop one frame with ffmpeg? All the other frames should point to the first with no changes, maybe like a recusion

Tags: loops, video, encoding, ffmpeg, frame

I want to make a long video from a single image in ffmpeg.

I need it to be fastly encodeable and at the end the video should have a small file size.

**Is it possible to fill the video with frames that point to the preivous(or the first) frame with no changes?**

I tried with this code, but it was slow and made a big file:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -shortest -preset ultrafast -t 3600 output.mp4
```

Comment: How are you going to use the output? Where?

Comment: I just need a very long video. I know there are different better solutions, like looping a little segment, but I need a very long one.

Comment: But it would already help if I can fix the encoding fps at a stable value. Now it is dropping 1-2 encoding fps / every second.(and getting slower)

Comment: It's possible to encode this quickly. But it won't be a small file.

Comment: And how would you do this quickly? (if big file is ok)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps:

1) Encode a short loop, say, 30 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 5 -i image.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -t 30 looped.mp4
```

2) Loop the encode for desired duration.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i looped.mp4 -c copy -t 3600 output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this solves the half of my problem! Maybe someone will know a fast and small file solution.

Comment: Depending on final use case, we can remove most frames.

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help - enter it all on a single line and it will stream a single image (called test.jpg) repeatedly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71885708/18795194 for my post and an explanation of the parameters.

```
ffmpeg 
-loop 1 
-fflags +genpts 
-framerate 1/30 
-i test.jpg 
-c:v libx264 
-vf fps=25 
-pix_fmt yuvj420p 
-crf 30 
-f fifo -attempt_recovery 1 -recovery_wait_time 1 
-f flv rtmp://localhost:5555/video/test
```